# select2 for zurb foundation 5

Tags: jquery-select2, zurb-foundation-5

someone have ported [select2](https://select2.github.io/) 4.0 for using it with zurb foundation 5?

something like [this](https://gist.github.com/cviebrock/8056741) but for select2 version 4.X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this gist](https://gist.github.com/icyz/abd2582c90e7535016d0). Tested in Chrome, FF, IE, Edge (last version)